# Get value by xPath knowing only the child of another node - selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I have some problem. I have a few checkboxes but there are no id or name for tags. Structure looks like this:

[image]

I would like to get green value but I only know red value: name=onlyWebsite. But this is different node.

Ofcourse when I do: `//input[@name='onlyWebsite']//i` this doesn't work.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to go to `check` from `onlyWebsite`, you may try the below xpath :

```
//input[@name='onlyWebsite']/following-sibling::span/descendant::i
```

if there are **multiple span's** as a `following-sibling`, you can try this :

```
//input[@name='onlyWebsite']/following-sibling::span[1]/descendant::i
```